# How to have a good communication with OPC?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, opc

I have an application with a thread for use OPC. this thread make a connexion with an OPC Factory Server and to receive the notification of the automation.

OPC : v 3.40.2808.0

Langage : Pascal , IDE : Delphi XE 2

The connexion with the server is good and notification is comming. but time to time, the service is not perfectly and my application not receive all the notification.

I'm not sure the issue come from my code but for explain a little:

```
GestOPC = class(TThread)
    contructor Create(suspendu:boolean);
    destructor Destroy;override;
    procedure C******; // Called by connexion
    private
        procedure Execute;override;
        procedure CallGestOPCMainLabelAtt(const s : string);// IU Calling 
        procedure Call****;
        procedure Call****;
        procedure Call****;
    public
        sCallIHM :string;
        ***: boolean;
        ***: LongInt;
        ThreadListNotif: TThreadList,
        ServeurIF : OPCServer;
        OPCDataCallBack:IOPCDataCallBack;
        Buffer_notif : ^TNotif;
        procedure connexion;
    end;

TOPCDataCallback = class ( TInterfacedObject, IOPCDataCallback)
public 
    function OnDataChange(.....)HResult;stdcall;
    function OnReadComplete(.....)HResult;stdcall;
    function OnWriteComplete(.....)HResult;stdcall;
    function OnCancelComplete(.....)HResult;stdcall;
end;
```

OnDataChange of OPC's Thread : It's the event for reception of notification

```
function TOPCDataCallback.OnDataChange ( dwTransid : DWORD; hgroup:OPCHANDLE; hrMasterquality: HResult;
hrMastererror : HResult;dwCount : DWORD;phClientItems:POPCHANDLEARRAY;pvValues: POleVariantArray;
pwQualities:PWordArray; pftTimeStamps : PFileTimeArray; pErrors :PResultList ): HResult;

var 
ClientItems :POPCHANDLEARRAY;
Values: POleVariantArray;
Qualities : PWordArray;
i,iCountBadItem:integer;

Begin
    if not bClosing then ///It's to not do anything if the app is closing.
    begin
        //Initialisation 
        iCountBadItem := 0; //this is for count during debbugging all notification unreadable
        Result := s_OK;
        ClientItems := POPCHANDLEARRAY (phClientItems);  
        Values := POleVariantArray(pvValues); 
        for i := 0 to dwCount -1 do 
        begin 
            if Qualities[i] = OPC_QUALITY_GOOD then 
            begin
                new(ClientOPC.Buffer_notif); 
                ClientOPC.Buffer_notif^.groupe_handle.indice_type1 := hGroup;
                ClientOPC.Buffer_notif^.item_client := ClientItems[i];
                ClientOPC.Buffer_notif^.valeur_item := Value[i];
                ClientOPC.ThreadListNotif.Add(ClientOPC.Buffer_Notif);
                      //This list is used in another Thread with LockList for use the notification.
            end
            else 
                iCountBadItem := iCountBadItem+1;
         end;
      end;
```

My procedure Execute of the OPC Thread is empty to be sure i have a good reception :

```
procedure GestOPC.Execute; 
begin
    NameThreadForDebugging('GestOPC');
    while (not Terminated) do 
    begin 
        sleep(100);
    end;
end;
```

My thread is created by the FormCreate event of my main form with :

```
     ClientOPC := GestOPC.Create(false);
     ClientOPC.FreeOnTerminate := false;
```

And the connexion is launch by a ButtonClick' Event :

```
     ClientOPC.Connexion;
```

The function connexion began by create the receiver TOPCDataCallBack, make the connect with Ofs, make SQL call on a database, and finish with a dynamic modification of my interface (an reason of the OPC is on a thread is for not freeze my interface during the connexion ) .

For my IU Calling i use this struct :

```
sCallIHM := "Ceci est un exemple de mon travail ;) ";
Queue( 
    procedure 
        begin 
        CallGestOPCMainLabelAtt( sCallIHM );
        end ) ;
```

How can i upgrade that for be sur to receive all my message?

Thank's for reading =)

Answer (score 4):

This code is completely misunderstanding how to use `TThread`.  Your `Execute` method does nothing, so as far as the application design is concerned *there is no thread*.  All of your `GestOPC` functions are simply being executed on whatever thread is calling them.  Since you are using `Queue` and the [documentation explicitly states](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) ***Warning : Do not call Queue from within the main thread.***, this is an obvious error.

Calling `Queue` here may not be a bug, of course.  You haven't told us anything about your OPC library and certainly *some* OPC libraries raise events on a worker thread.  If this is the case, you have avoided a bug by luck - if it is not the case then you have a bug by design.  Only you can read the library documentation determine which is the case.

The design of this application is all wrong.  Suggest you forget about `TThread` for the moment, turn your `TThread` into a regular class, get rid of the useless `Execute` method, get rid of the calls to `Queue` (and `Synchronize`, if you have any), and see what happens. Then take some time to learn how `TThread` works and how to write correct multi-threaded code - especially if you don't know what you are doing, it is essential to get your code working single-threaded first, then work on a threading model. This helps to separate bugs caused by thread issues and bugs caused by the code itself.

Furthermore, missing data from an OPC server can also come from temporal aliasing.  The OPC server is sampling your field device at some polling rate, which can vary from system to system and from tag to tag.  This polling rate can be on the order of 10-100ms or more.  If the value in the field device is changing faster than this rate the OPC server can miss the change and many event-based clients will therefore not raise change notifications.  It is therefore critical that you ensure fast-changing hardware states are latched or queued in some way if you must be certain to observe them.  When debugging, you should be certain that this is not the source of missed change notifications.

Comment: Sorry i'm begginner ^^'

Comment: @Guillaume Don't be sorry.  One of the most important lessons when starting out is to not try to do too much at once - otherwise you end up drowning in problems that you don't understand.  Start with a simple solution and get it working first, then add complexity later.

Comment: Sorry I'm beginner ^^' But  "Do not call Queue from the main thread" i not using that on the main thread, no ?  At first , this apply is an multithread app  i have to upgrade for pass on MQTT Communication . I haven't synchronize for no freeze my thread on a IU modification. So if I understand good , i take my connection and my OPCDataCallBack and put it in my main thread ? My issue if i make that is the SQL call, too long and really long freeze of my UI. After create this thread, it have really change the freeze and it's very nice. sorry for my english.. (this web site make joke with edit ^^)

Comment: @Guillaume No, if you are calling `ClientOPC.Connexion;` in a button click handler then it is definitely being executed on the main thread.  The *only* code in a `TThread` that is executed on the worker thread is the `Execute` method and this begins either when you call `MyThread.Create(false)` (do not create suspended) or when you call `MyThread.Start` (if you `Create(true)` - create suspended).  Otherwise, a `TThread` is just a regular class and its methods are executed on whichever thread that calls them.  If a method is not called within the `Execute` method, it does not run on the thread.

Comment: @Guillaume Therefore, if you have freezing issues that are better now, it is because of some other change in your code and not because you are calling the methods in a background thread.

Comment: i'm trying to change ^^

Comment: Ok, in reality, nothing has changed, I followed your advice and put all things right, and I always try to catch the event with WireShark to observe the loss of data from the data transmission. Fair, the event of which I speak is only up to 4 notification in the little I've seen. Nothing has changed in either ... I hope the test I set up for that night will offer me more information.
 Sorry for the reaction time, my boss put me on a more urgent project in the meantime ...

Comment: This morning , at 06h05.33 , 3 exemple of my app run on 3 computer and follow the same OFS, 2 of its have take the notification. The third have never receive the IOPCDataCallBack's message ... Someone can explain me how it's possible?

Comment: PS: The app haven't be disconnected by the server.

Comment: @Guillaume In brief, I don't know what else to suggest.  Factory OPC is a game of a million details and you've given us only a few.  We can't see the problem with the same clarity that you can.  I can't provide any more answers than I already have and it isn't clear to me that you've actually read and understood everything in my answer.

Comment: I understand what's you tell:i'm lost in this issue because i don't understand the source of my problem. If you think i'm a vampire, it's perhaps because my english level is poor. 
If your advice is good and have help me to have a better understanding of programming with thread, you haven't resolve my issue because i'm in the same progress at the beginning. Just my answer is in bad way because the information at the beginning is not in the good direction. I understand that only now, before the try of this morning. I think close and open new question with better information. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, much more information would be needed, and no your English is not a problem.  I understand you perfectly.  If you have made changes to your code since the original version you posted then you need to share them so that we can see what you are doing now.  Nobody can read the code on your screen unless you share it with us.  With OPC you also must check the configuration of all components in the system - if you have done those checks you must tell us what you have done, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: @Guillaume For example, what is the server configuration, what is the client configuration - synchronous or async communication setup?  Polling time?  Tag update intervals?  Which server software are you using?  This is a very complex problem and if the solution is difficult for you to find it is even more difficult for us to try to help with very much less information.